# When must an explicit call to super constructor be used?

Tags: java, inheritance, super

I am learning about `super()` constructor and I ran into this statement:

> Since the inherited instance variables should be initialized, and the base class constructor is designed to do that, then an explicit call to `super()` should always be used.

What does this statement mean?

Except for the fact that implicit call can result in an error if the base class has not defined a no-argument constructor?

Comment: In short, whenever you are not happy about the default choice (no-arg constructor) of the implicit `super();`, you should explicitly select the constructor you want `super(...);`. If you are happy with that choice, you can keep it implicit, as simple as that.

Answer (score 2):

I think the quoted paragraph is a little bit misleading because you only need to explicitly call a parametrised super() if you are not happy with the unparametrised implicit super() call.

You would also have to do a parametrised super() call if the base class only has parametrised constructors.

Answer (score 1):

This sentence you quoted doesn't explicitly say that you need to have 0 argument constructor in your class. The point of the sentence is that all the variables that are part of parent class should be initialized and you initialize those variables with a constructor, therefore you should call parent class constructor inside of your child class constructor. Doesn't matter what is the number of arguments of parent class constructor.